# Extrinsic's string parameter lower bound validation

Tags: extrinsic, validation, boundedvec

I want to validate the extrinsic string parameters like `name`, `title`, `cid`, etc. The type should be capable of min/max length validation. And checking the lower bound is impossible with the [current implementation of `frame_support::BoundedVec`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/storage/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html). But [`BoundedVec` from std library](https://docs.rs/bounded-vec/latest/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html) has a lower bound functionality.

It's more of a suggestion for a Substrate team. I assume the only way is a custom type with all of the serialization rules. Maybe other suggestions on how to solve this string validation problem or if it even makes sense? For sure, I can do it with `!ensure` macros.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonble idea, and should be doable in a backwards compatible way. Open an issue on Substrate, and if you are up for it, perhaps you can also implement it!